# What if we were born incorporeal

Tags: internal-consistency

As we are born with bodies, we are corporeal, but what if that was different? What if, perhaps, we were an energy without a shell, nor appearance. What if we sensed using waves intersecting with that energy. This is a question made for the spirits and ghosts in [Project:Numens](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1hkBLKnedsms0LGEtRKHax57zqlbiyjBiJaayFa5lV-I/edit). As these beings aren’t bound how we are, they would react, and evolve(if even possible) differently.

Comment: Mainly looking for key factors, though I can’t conjure many as I’m not an expert upon intelligence or spiritual intelligence or the such.

Comment: If you are using the word energy in the sense of physics, then "energy without a shell" is meaningless; energy is just a number describing the capacity of a physical system to work: there is no such thing as energy disassociated from the physical system. If you are using the word energy in the theological sense, then the question is even more meaningless. (Some variants of Christian theology use the phrase "godly energies" for what are called in Latin "actûs". I don't know the English for this; maybe "appearances" or "activities"?)

Comment: Ya, I do see your point, it hits quite hard and precise.

Comment: Welcome droko, please take our [tour] and refer to the [help] for guidance as to our ways. Enjoy the site. Questions like this - there is the difficulty of us not really understanding what you're asking as you've not clearly defined your terms. There's also the issue that the link you give leads to an incoherent list of apparently disparate things with no context or explanation (not to mention the file is BIG).

Comment: The link should take you to a google docs. I don’t quite get what you mean by big but I assume you mean loading time, and yes that doc does take a while to load as it had a number of pictures due to it being the expanded version of the entire project(it contains everything).

Comment: This question seems a little bit too broad. Try picking a certain problem that you need to solve for these beings

Comment: I’ll try your suggestion as soon as I con conjure a more focused one(or as close to a focused one as I can make in the near future).

Comment: Upvoted because I feel this is an interesting fictional subject. I think there would be a difference.. you'll have a energy realm, and a substance realm. Both realms can only interact by using specific abilities. I think it would be very individual, like "fictional friends", or "fictional twins". Whether the "energy" partner of the relation manifests itself to anyone else..

Comment: I have considered these as a possibility, and I think it is theoretically plausible(but only in seer prospect for me) as I lack mainly of the assets experts would have, such as degrees and the sort.

Comment: Why would a being only consisting of energy need to be born ? Suppose the mother will give birth, she will know her child is there, but none of her (normal) senses tell her that. A frightening experience. Again: I find it difficult to answer your question, without filling in the subject and your story. I'd like to have some starting point.. some anchor to comment on. Else it would become "material" versus "immaterial" only, and there are many topics about that already. You let the entity *be born*. How does that work, can the father see - or sense - the child ?

Comment: I ,hypothetically, propose that these beings are created souly from the mind(though complications are proposed as well). Theoretically their creator is gifted in creativity, and though development(noticed or not) a entity is born.

Comment: Honestly, this is the kind of worldbuilding question I'd like to see more of here. This forum isn't entirely for "science as we know it". Or even for existence as we'd like to expect. That said, droko, I agree with @IchthysKing -- either pick a problem or try to focus on one single aspect of your spirit beings. (Also note that humans are not simply corporeal either; rather a spirit-body composite.)

Comment: I’ll likely have to more research on things such as the human mind before I can accurately portray the entities. For now however I’ll have drafts as “footnotes” for how the project is going(in the form of books of characters, which can be found in the link). This project currently is simply experimental and isn’t really to be taken with all the seriousness in the world, but it doesn’t hurt to be criticized. I hope I keep the project running til it’s completion(if that’s even possible).

Answer (score 4):

*What if we sensed using waves intersecting with that mass of energy.*

Then there would be very little difference. "Waves intersecting with our mass" is precisely how humans perceive the world already. Our strongest, primary senses are vision and hearing, and vision is the result of waves of light hitting our retinas, while hearing is the result of waves of sound hitting out eardrums.

Comment: Due to limited knowledge, that was the best example I could conjure. What I was think was that it was a mass of pure energy, and that, somehow, that mass could perceive waves intersecting throughout it. As you see there’s a lot I need to build.

Comment: +1 touching the essence but I propose to leave out "mass" because I think.. mass is the wrong word. I've proposed an edit to the question, maybe this is just a language thing. I think "amount" is meant, or nothing at all. Just energy. Or lots of energy, "a mass" of it. The incorporeal birth involves an entity consisting of energy only. It has no mass, as I understand the question..

Comment: When I was using the word mass, I was trying to get across that it was basically a “collection” of something, which is quite vague, but I seriously have little to accurately convey what I mean. Also I think I used the word mass as some of these “entities” (mainly in the project called spirits and ghosts) have some sort of power, at least I wish them to have some.

Comment: @drokodragonten I feel it's difficult to actually answer your question, without filling in the story. Maybe you could describe some of the backgrounds ?

Comment: The original is the project is kind of complicated(as is many things I do). Mainly I was thinking “what if we didn’t need things bags of meat, I surly don’t want mine”.